# open xml error : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, openxml

I am trying to export given datatable to xlsx file using open xml.

I have written following code :

```
private void ExportToExcelFileOpenXML(DataTable dt, string destination)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dtCopy = new DataTable();
    dtCopy = dt.Copy();
    ds.Tables.Add(dtCopy);
    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {           

        var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

        foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {

            var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
            sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
            string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

            uint sheetId = 1;
            if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
            {
                sheetId =
                    sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
            }

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

            List<String> columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }


            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                foreach (String col in columns)
                {
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this function I am getting error on :

```
using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
```

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mAn
>   exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> ```
>  Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.
> ```

variable destination has value :

> IncorrectRecordsUploaded_9/9/2015 9:48:23 AM.xlsx

How can I resolve this error?

I have tried :

```
destination.replace("/","//");
```

But same error was coming on that line.

When I renamed a file to `IncorrectRecordsUploaded.xlsx` it started throwing me :

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessExAn exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\IncorrectRecordsUploaded.xlsx' is denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You desrcibed two different errors.

**First error** occured because of invalid filename chars.
There are a few symbols, that deniend in naming: `<`, `>`, `:`, `"`, `/`,  `\`, `|`, `?`, `*`. Also you can check the rules for [naming files and folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247) on MSDN.

If you create destination path by yourself you can use this regex, to remove all unallowed symbols:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var pattern = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
var r = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(pattern)));
tempFileName = r.Replace(tempFileName, "_");
```

Your **second error** occured because you haven't access to this path. Try to save your file to another place (`Documents` or just `C:/`).